# mysql select '%[..]%' doesn't show any entries

Tags: php, mysql

In a field of my mysql-db i've values like that [1][3][10]… Now i would like so search only entries with the value [3]. I searched with this SQL-Select:

```
SELECT * FROM thb_wine WHERE catID = '%[3]%'
```

Unfortunately it doesn't show the entry. What is wrong?

thanks for your help
Thomas

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
SELECT * FROM thb_wine WHERE catID LIKE '%[3]%'
```

When you compare with single value you use = operator , but when you use % signs to find partial match you need to use LIKE operator

Comment: Sorry, I'm so…. My focus was only on the '%..' .Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn more about operators in MySQL. The 'LIKE' operator is best suited in your case as you would like to search entries containing only specific values. The %,_ and [charlist] are the wildcards for this operator. '%' is a substitute for zero or any no. of characters.'_' is a substitute for one character, whereas '[charlist]' is for sets and ranges of characters to match.
So, Your query should be like:

`SELECT * FROM thb_wine WHERE catID LIKE '%[3]%'`